# Reasons for man to marry after 30

Tags: practical-islam, nikah

I would like to clear these points before asking this question:

1. I am fully aware that marriage is sun nah(Highly recommended sun nah).
2. I am fully aware that marriage is a natural way to fulfill your desires and remain chaste.
3. I am fully aware that Allah provides sustenance and a person should not be worried about it.

But after testifying to all of the above points I have the following concerns regarding marriage:

1. Sustenance is provided by Allah but the person has to earn it. A person becomes stable at the age of 30+ in the present time if he completes his education because of the scarcity of jobs and competition in the market. Now the point to ponder is that the average age in Pakistan is 66 years so what is the point of marrying at the age of 30 when half of the life has already passed without any partner?
2. If I don't marry I can do a lot of other stuff freely with more dedication . For example I can support my parents fully financially without worrying about saving some money for my children and wife . I can give more charity , I can spend more time in performing my religious duties.

To cut the long story short what is the point of getting married at the age of 30 when half of the life has already passed and you can do far better things with your life rather than paying the bills and doing multiple jobs to earn a middle class standard?

Answer (score 2):

Your question has multiple aspects:

1. "Sustenance is provided by Allah but the person has to earn it." --> which one is it? Imam Hussain has said sustenance is of 2 kinds: The one that you seek yourself and the one that Allah brings to you. For instance your parents call you and invite over for dinner or some gives you a gift... you didn't do anything to earn it... Allah provided it for you. And Allah has said it that he would provide. Also don't think of رزق in materialistic ways i.e. sustenance could be a great job, education, house, car, etc. it could also be a happy mind, a lovely spouse, intellect, great children to leave behind, coupled rizq beacuse of you nurturing them!
2. In marriage you give up somethings to gain more...and don't look at yourself in the age of 30, you are powerful now, think about the age of 50, when you are a bit weaker, a bit more alone, wouldn't you like to have a spouse who would love you regardless of all your faults, children to leave behind for the afterlife as باقی الصالحات? **i.e. leaving righteous children behind is like leaving an eternal tree of good deeds behind, something that can not be compared to money**
3. Allah's way of handling things are not that mathematic as you think, maybe perhaps if you get married, then Allah would triple your sustenance and you will have to devote less time to work and could be more with them, maybe you children would be a good aid for them, maybe your spouse would be a good aid for them.
4. A tangent note, when you get married your intellect (عقل) would increase as a result of showing patience for your family...usually people who are married are 2X-3X mature than those who are not (No offense to anyone). And by having a more intellectual and humble mind, worshiping Allah and having patience and forbearance for him would become easier

Comment: All the benefits of marriage can only be utilized if a person marries at young age which is not possible in the present world.

Comment: @user2186997
My dearest friend, take a look into these verses, perhaps they would be very reflecting for you.

For having more faith
http://quran.com/39/53
http://quran.com/65/2
http://quran.com/65/3
-----
For the unexpeced:
http://quran.com/4/19
http://quran.com/2/216
-----
For similar situations for prophets
http://quran.com/11/72
http://quran.com/11/73
------
I do agree that getting married sooner has its benefits, but I also think that getting married now is 10X better than not ever getting married.
Compare yourself with a people that are 5 years older than you not younger and catch them!